# "Uncaught Error: element not found list" Error in uploader.jquery.js

Tags: jquery, fine-uploader

I am trying to get fine-uploader work in my project. I began with [Basic Setup](http://fineuploader.com/demos.html#basic-setup) (ditto qq-template script from demo page) and it worked. But I need customized UI. So I started using 'template' option. Now when I set 'template' option:

```
$('#fine-uploader').fineUploader({
        debug: true,
        template: 'qq-template',
        request: {
          endpoint: '<%= upload_csv_people_organization_path(@organization) %>'
        }
      });
```

I get "Uncaught Error: element not found list" on like fineuploader.jquery.js?body=1:2478.

[browser page Screenshot](http://grab.by/tkiw)

Also I'm using it in Rails project, I get the uploader.jquery.js file from `gem 'fileuploader-rails', '~> 3.5'` [fileuploader-rails gem](https://github.com/lebedev-yury/fileuploader-rails)

Please help.Thanks!

Comment: Can you confirm that you are using Fine Uploader 3.5?

Comment: I embedded it in my rails asset pipeline using [Fine Uploader 3.5 for Rails gem](https://github.com/lebedev-yury/fileuploader-rails). So I guess the gem is using fine-uploader 3.5.

Comment: here is the fine-uploader jquery file that I extracted from the gem [uploader.jquery.js](http://tny.cz/2c585998). Password is 123456.   I also added CSRF token in the `setHeaders` function for it to work with Rails. `xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content"));`

Answer (score 2):

You are using Fine Uploader 3.5, which is over 8 months old.  It looks like you are using documentation from version 4+ to configure your instance though.  This will never work, especially when it comes to templating, since templating changed drastically in version 4.0.

Before version 4.0, the `template` and `fileTemplate` options existed, and, by default, took HTML strings that specified the respective templates.  You have effectively replaced the template with a non-HTML string, which is why Fine Uploader is not working for you.

Consider upgrading to the latest version of Fine Uploader.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to address this issue. In my code, I use Fineuploader and Image CRUD. And both of this use Fineuploader CSS and JS with separate filepath. For information, Image CRUD using CSS and JS from fineuploader library.

The reality is Image CRUD using different version of Fineuploader CSS and JS.

[image: So, delete (or comment) css and JS from Image CRUD and use from Fineuploader instead.]